# Why is NDK generating shared library for x86 with text relocation even after setting -fPIC flag?

Tags: android, android-ndk, sip, pjsip

I'm using PJSIP/PJSUA2 with Android project. I've built libpjsua2.so shared library for armeabi, armeabi-v7 and x86 with -fPIC flag. The libs are also linked with OpenSSL 1.0.2h statically which were built with -fPIC flag. All libs loads properly on device with Android 4.4 to 6.0 except x86 in which it shows text relocation error. [Build script](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7ZX6TyTOI6uMTBaRVltSXU0WVk) builds two versions of the lib-

android-9 (for API level upto 15 and no x86)
android-16 (for API level 16+)

Why on x86, text relocation is occurring even with -fPIC flag?

Comment: I've got the same problem for duobango, but only for NEON.

Comment: @Shark I don't know what I changed, x86 is now working without text relocation. My minimum target is now Android-16.

Answer (score 0):

Today, I got the same error messages when testing my app with Android 7.0 on a Nexus 5 Emulator. I solved my issue by changing the targetSDKVersion to 22.

This is just a short term workaround..